# php security and ajax requests

Tags: php, security, jquery, xss

I have some simple scripts on my site that allow users to accomplish tasks like
calculating date differences, do math calculations etc. The website is about 95%
pure html (not php generated), except for some jquery/ajax that posts user input
to server-side to do the calculations. The ajax code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script/calc.php",
    data: { userval:val},
    success: function(response){
    //display response
    }
});
```

When user input values are/should be numbers I add (int) before the post variable on php
file "calc.php", even though in terms of security I dont think it can bring any problems.

Im thinking of filtering http_referer, so the php file only gets requests from my site
(to avoid any abuse) but I've read that counting only on http_referer isn't the ultimate
trick because it relies on user's browser and sometimes it can be empty. On the other
hand I know ajax by default won't allow to post to another domain, but there's a hack for
that too.

Im not a hardcore security guy, I know some basics, so is there anything you guys
can suggest me? What could possibly go wrong in this case. Note that I dont use any
database, there's only a php file that does some calculations and nothing more (nothing
like accessing any directory, file uploading or such things).

Is there anything I else should seriously consider, to prevent server abuse, xss attacks or
similiar?

Edit: So basically calc.php has a structure like this(very simple)

//expecting an integer
$userval = (int) $_POST['userval'];

$total_sum = ($userval*15) * (150* ($userval-2));

echo $total_sum;
unset($total_sum);

//end//

Comment: Most security comes down to sanitizing user input data. Most breeches are from a lack thereof.

Comment: Well, to tell you if there are any problems with `script/calc.php`, we need to see the source (or at least a chunk of it).

Answer (score 0):

1. AJAX uses JavaScript which has SOP(SAME ORGIN POLICY) read about it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
2. Check what input you have. If you expect numbers check them in php and cast with (int) or intval()
3. What is input data needed for? If you don't put anything into database, you don't change your files, what do you use input for?
4. You can always use regular expressions if you have strings and validate them also you should escape them depending on where you want to store them. But numbers make things easier.
5. The script you've provided is save.
6. Good practice is also logging all suspicious tries and if there are too many, you should block user.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. So as I mentioned most of the scripts are calculators. The php expects one or two values, makes some calculations and then outputs the result and posts it back :)

Comment: intval(), is_numeric(), casting - all what you need :)

Comment: Also, if I may ask an off-topic question, this isn't really a hardcore task for php, will I have any problem with server load, considering a case that 6k users will be using my site simultaneously, there is no database, so echoing doing some multiplications/additions and echoing the result is everything php has to do.

Comment: there will be no problem, but I don't understand why not to use java script? If you use JS then you don't have to worry because all calculations are done by browser which is better.

Comment: I use some javascript and about 50% of the stuff is done server side, I do it to protect my code. Javasript can be read and stolen easily.
It's something I've done to avoid an easy copy of my stuff, it can be
dublicated by a programmer of course :)

Comment: Yeah but I guess there are tools that will de-obfuscate that code. Still no guarantee, furthermore, if I obfuscate the code, a simple "Save as" would copy the page right? So the stealer will have a functional copy of my script. What do I do then, call the police? lol